# MySQL - restrict large queries based on user

Tags: mysql

Does MySQL has options to restrict an user from running large queries? Lets say the max number of records the user can query is only 10000 rows or 10MB.

Edit:
Goal is I want to give select access to bunch of tables in my database to a user. I am Ok with them selecting few items at a time but not allow them to dump/join tables lets say for last two months of data (since that's a lot of workload and might bog down other services that are running in the server)

So if the user requests such query, it should error out and return some errorcode corresponding to "exceeded limit" or something related.

Comment: @iBrazilian2, that's not a related question.

Comment: True, that was a wrong example.

Comment: Even queries with small resultsets can use a lot of resources. What is your goal? I think it's not usual that end users can create queries of their own.

Comment: @VMai, I have updated my question with the goaal

Answer (score 1):

In combination with [`--safe-udpates`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates), you can use `select_limit` and `max_join_size`.

Since you specify these settings in the command line (and/or *my.cnf*), it requires a server restart.

Unfortunately, this is not "per user". The variables are not dynamic.

You could (rather easily) append `LIMIT` to the user's query (since it's the last clause in the query).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put a limit for a query just use the limit, in execution of a query do this example:

```
SELECT id FROM idlist WHERE processed=0 ORDER BY id LIMIT 10000;
```

Comment: Its not my query, its other users query. So I cant make sure they implement limit in it

Comment: yes I know but it is just an example you can apply to Users, if you use limit as a variable not exactly have to be applied 10000 this can be a variable $LimitUser, Example:  SELECT id FROM user WHERE age>0 ORDER BY id LIMIT $LimitUser;

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such settings present but you can create a view like below

```
create view myview 
as
select * from table
order by some_column   
limit 10000
```

You can change the query with which you are creating view based on any specific condition like

```
create view myview 
as
select * from table
where some_condition 
order by some_column   
limit 10000
```

Then you can assign `select` privilege to this view for those particular restricted users.

```
GRANT SELECT ON myview to restricted_user1
```

Comment: Those particular users will sometimes get wrong answers to their questions. I don't think that's a way I would recommend.

Comment: @VMai, unless there is any particular option present in MySQL (which I am not aware about); I see this as a solution to what OP trying to achieve. Also, I will be glad to know as why you don't think it's recommended.

Comment: Because they get wrong results, as I said. They get wrong results because the queries may missing the relevant rows of the original table.

Comment: @VMai, as per posted question, user just need to be restricted to fetch not more than 10K rows. You may say that the query I have given will give any 10K rows. I will add a `order by`. I think that will be good enough?

Comment: I can't say. Let's assume I want to know the count of the values of a certain column: `SELECT col1, COUNT(col1) FROM mytable GROUP BY col1` with 2500 different values for col1 in a million rows of mytable. How to achieve that with such a view?

Comment: @VMai, correct and in such case user can either go for a view/query (OR) procedure/Query. Am not saying, my answer is **THE** solution but rather a possibility/alternative; cause there is no such per user query setting present (IMO).